# SolidWorks saves PDF with raster graphic

Tags: cad, solidworks

I hope the SolidWorks help will grow in here - So I test my luck with a question.

When saving a drawing .SLDDRW (solidworks drawing) as PDF, it is mostly vector graphics. However, when using API from MS Access, the 3D view is sometimes raster. It gets unreadable when projected to A3 paper. If I then save manually as PDF, it is vector graphics. I tried to record the macro and play it, without a different outcome.

I know that when making a "shaded" view, it will always be raster, but a pure line view should be vectors.

Anyone else had this annoying issue and possibly a fix?
Applies for both SW 2016 and 2018.

I can provide example.

(SolidWorks support does not cover MS Access API)

Comment: What code are you running?

Comment: @AndrewK Im running the API through VBA in MS Access 2016.

Comment: As far as I know, when you link or embed a file in Access, the image that is saved is a preview (similar to the windows preview), so it will never be a vector graphics file. Have you created a Report in Access with the default size of an A3 sheet? What you're describing seems like what would happen if your report is A4 or A5 sized and you upscale the print. I might be wrong here, but it's a place to start.

Comment: @Rafael I can see that 99% of the files are correct vector graphics when saved. Its the same routine. Can't find any differences but the 1% of the files that are turned into raster.